# Legend breaks cut off at the limits ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting different types of graphs where my legend has the colorbar of the values in my graph in log like in the image below:

[image: ColorBar breaks: per decade]

The code that gives something like this is:

```
2Dmap <- ggplot(x, aes(L, W, fill = R)) +
        geom_raster() + coord_fixed() +
        scale_fill_viridis(name="R", trans = "log", direction = -1, labels=trans_format('log10',math_format(10^.x)), breaks=cycle.breaks,
                           limits=c(10^(floor(log10(min(x$R[x$R > 0] )))), 10^(ceiling(log10(max(x$R)))) ) )+
        theme_bw() + coord_fixed(ratio=12)
      2Dwmap <- 2Dwmap + theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
        theme(legend.key.width=unit(2.2, "cm")) + 
        theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15)) +
        theme(legend.position="bottom",
              title = element_text(size = 20),
              axis.title.x=element_text(size = 20),
              axis.title.y=element_text(size = 20), 
              axis.text.x = element_text(size = 18),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18),
              legend.title = element_text(size = 18),
              legend.text = element_text(size = 16))
```

So, I'm trying to look for a good way to avoid my limiting breaks to be cut off.

Any1 any ideas ?

Sorry I cannot share data to make a reproducible example :)

Comment: What prevents you creating suitable values to make a [mcve]?

Comment: @Toby Speight, Maybe downvoting might be a bit brutal here, it is a new user! at: Marios Barlas, we need some minimal data to work on. What do you mean with "I cannot share data" : You are not able to or you are not allowed to? In any case, best is to create a simple data frame that reduces the variables to the minimum necessary. Made up data, so absolutely legal. If you are not able to, use dput(your dataframe) and we can use the output.